# How to find functions satisfying $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=f(x-y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

We are given a non-constant differentiable function $f(x)$ which satisfies the relation

$$\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}=f(x-y)$$

From the given data, how do I determine $f(x)$?

It is clear to me that the function should be of the form $a^{kx}$ but I can't really figure out how to come up with a rigorous proof. Also,is there any way to tell that $a^{kx}$ is in fact the only solution? I have tried substituting $x$ and $y$ with different values but I couldn't really get anywhere.

Comment: No need to have both $a,k$ as parameters (as $a^k$ is just another $a$).  Hint:  let $a=f(a)$  Show that $f(x+1)=a\times f(x)$.  Deduce that $f(n)=a^n$ for $n\in \mathbb N$.  Deduce that $f(x)=a^x$ for $x\in \mathbb Q$.  Now use continuity.

Comment: Relate your problem to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), which has a well-known answer.

Comment: @lulu, do you mean $f(1)=a$ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  That was a typo. I meant $f(1)=a$.

Comment: Let $g(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}{a^x}$, then g(x) also has the same property as f(x) no matter what is the value of a, as long as a make g(x) a well-defined differentiable function.

Comment: Let $h(x)=\ln f(x)$, then it's Cauchy's equation right away.